# Are there any enemies required for the Death By Disco achievement that can be missed?

Tags: achievements, ratchet-and-clank-2016

Are there any enemies that only appear once that are required the the Death By Disco achievement?

For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDjbR9v7kYE) starts with the Glowing Slug enemies that you see on Veldin in the opening sequence and nowhere else.

Are they actually required for the achievement (since they do only appear once afaik) and are there other enemies or bosses that are required for the achievement that also only appear one time and are not available later?

This, of course, assumes a single playthrough. Yes, you can do a second playthrough but just so to know if you can go all the way to the final fight and backtrack and still get it even having never used the weapon before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any enemies required for the Death By Disco achievement that can be missed?

**Yes**, there's plenty.

Bosses and minibosses definitely count towards it and they can only be fought once on a single playthrough.

On top of this, a few levels feature paths that *cannot* be revisited after an initial visit. The Glowing Slugs on Veldin at night are an excellent example of this, but also the 'Ranger Tryout' flamethrower bots (Veldin, first level) and the enemies on the Deplanetiser (both visits) cannot be revisited.

> You can go all the way to the final fight and backtrack and still get it even having never used the weapon before

Unfortunately, this isn't true. On top of the bosses and single-path enemies listed above, later in the game

> Planet Novalis is destroyed.

If you haven't used the Groovitron there before that point you will be unable to use it against those enemies.

---

For reference, here are all the enemies that you need to affect with the Groovitron, by planet. The ones in Bold are the ones I'm pretty sure can only be fought once:

## Veldin

- 1 Horny Toad
- **2 Flamethrower Robot**
- **3 Glowing Slug**
- 4 Small Blarg Shooter
- 5 Dropship
- 6 Warbot (Version 1)

## Novalis

- 7 Robot Bird (Peckbot)
- 8 Yellow Grenade Launcher Robot

## Kerwan

- 9 Robot Dog (Kerwan Version)
- 10 Big Blarg Shooter
- 11 Helicopter
- **12 Green Tentacle on Train**

## Aridia

- 13 Sandshark
- 14 Sandshark Nest (Green Plant)
- 15 Constructobot

## Rilgar

- 16 Extermibot
- 17 Tank (Rilgar Version)
- 18 Large Amoeboid
- 19 Medium Amoeboid
- 20 Small Amoieboid
- 21 Pool Shark (On Floor / Not Swimming)
- 22 Pool Shark (Swimming)

## Nebula G34

- 23 Green Horned Toad
- 24 Alien Shooter
- 25 Brown Lizard (Snapper Version 1)
- 26 Alien Lizard (Snapper Version 2)
- **27 Snagglebeast (Boss)**

## Gaspar

- 28 Robot Dogs (Gaspar Version)
- 29 Turret Shooter
- 30 Flying Dinosaur
- 31 Small Red Robot with Blades
- 32 Robot Assembly Bot
- 33 Warbot (Version 2 with Jetpack)
- 34 Killer Crab
- 35 Telepathopus (Gaspar Version)

## Batalia

- 36 Blarg Bomb Thrower
- 37 Tank (Batalia Version)

## Quartu

- 38 Zurkon
- **39 Mrs. Zurkon (Boss)**

## Pokitaru

- 40 Puffer Fish
- 41 Telepathopus (Pokitaru Version)

## Deplanetizer

- 42 Blarg Jetpack Shooter
- 43 Dog with Glowing Eyes
- 44 Tank (Deplanetizer Version)

## Kalebo III

- 45 Warbot (Version 3, Red Color with Jetpack)

## Deplanetizer

- 46 Warbot (Version 4, Yellow Color)
- **47 Qwark (Boss)**
- **48 Dr. Nefarious**

Comment: I've heard some of these enemies are not actually required (like the pool shark while swimming, since it doesn't actually have a dance animation), but it's hard to tell for sure